# AJAX + Codeigniter live page load with function

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

UPDATED: This now works 100%.

These segements of code allowed a user to click a Delete button on the view, which sends an AJAX request to my controller to interact (delete a record) with the database.  Then feed back a result of what occured in the callback function to update the current view (without a page load) that the record was deleted and to hide the element.

View:

```
<?php
// Output the records
if($result)
{
    foreach ($result as $rows => $row) 
    {
        echo "<tr id=\"row" . $row['id'] . "\">";
            echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . " - " . $row['name'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['logo_path'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['date_created'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . "<a href=\"#\" id=\"" . $row['id'] . "\" class=\"delete\">Delete</a><br>" . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }

} else {
    echo "There are no platforms to show";
}
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
$("a.delete").click(function(e) 
{
    e.preventDefault();
    var platform_id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    var row = $(this).attr('id');

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "platform/delete",
        dataType: "json",
        data: 'platform_id='+platform_id,
        success: function(result){
            if (result.success == 1)
            {
                $("#row" + row).fadeOut();
                //document.getElementById(row).style.display = 'none'
            }
        },
        error: function(result){
            alert(result.message);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Controller:

```
function delete()
{
    $result=array(); 

    $this->load->model('platform_model');
    $platform_id = $this->input->post('platform_id');

    if($this->platform_model->delete($platform_id))
    {
        $result['success']= 1;
        $result['platform_id']= $platform_id;
        $result['message']= "Success";
    } else {
        $result['success']= 0;
        $result['message']= "Error";
    }

    die(json_encode($result));

}
```

Model:

```
function delete($platform_id)
{
    $this->db->where('id =', $platform_id);

    if ($this->db->delete('platforms'))
    {
        return TRUE;
    }
    else
    {
        return FALSE;
    }   
}
```

Comment: I had updated my question to be more specific to the problem at hand.  I dont appreciate @omar and others for closing my question without giving a chance to refine it.

Comment: Closing is not definite, questions are reopened very fast if improved as needed.

Comment: Excellent, I dont understand the downvoting then, it should be a flag or something else - but I guess Ill have to see how things are handled around here.  Anywho the question is now more targeted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

You don't need any form code to make this work. In your updated question there is missing where you define the `id` variable. Without it you will not be able to delete the record.

Data is sent by a HTTP POST request unregarded if it is a form that submits it. With your AJAX code data is sent as POST data also, to be handled by Codeigniter with the `$this->input->post()` array in your AJAX model method. A great tool to debug this process is Firebug wher you can see data posted and what is returned (Net/XHR tab)

In my example before I used the attribute `data-id` instead of `id` attribute as the latter need to be unique. I prefer that solution myself but you could use any attribute name except `id` (if the attribute value is repeated).

```
$('a.delete').click(function(e) 
{
   e.preventDefault();
   var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
   // your ajax call
```

Matching HTML as an anchor but could be a button or any other element:

```
<a href="#" data-id="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" class="delete">Delete</a>
```

The AJAX code is triggered from the clicking of the delete link, hence no need for any form.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have updated the question to be a bit more specific.  I was able to get the ajax function to work thanks to your help, mainly the e.preventDefault();.  Doing some research on the subject I cant find anything that reflects my new updated question.

Comment: I am doing what I can to figure this one out.  I toss in Alerts to see where the code is getting tripped up.  I installed Fiddler2 to help.  I am getting a "An Error Was Encountered The action you have requested is not allowed." POST /league/platform/delete HTTP/1.1 id=1 (500 Error) - I am running this on XAMPP locally, idk if that means there is a server configuration error.  I doubt it since im new to ajax

Comment: @jtherman OMG - I am using code igniter, and I had CSRF_protection enabled, this apparently adds hidden data to the ajax request automatically.  I turned it off and its starting to come along!

Comment: I have gotten it to work for the most part, I just need to reload the table data after the AJAX success and I will revise my answer!

Comment: See my latest update, I cant see to get the data to placed on the page.

Comment: Are you sure your delete controller actions echo out a reply? Check the XHR response with Firebug or similar...

Comment: Thats most likely the error - my delete function in my controller returns $platform_id - what should it return?  I added my delete function to the main post.

Comment: @jetheman thank you so much! I am almost there, I had to properly use the callback function.  See my update, I need one last piece before its complete!

Comment: Are you sure you dont want to hide the whole row? Well this is anyway the use for having an id. So either add a id for the link or for the TR tag. You could call it `id="row123"` (where 123 is your id) then just add to your success function `$('#row'+platform_id).hide();`

Comment: Funny you said that, I did just that, and Hide works, but oddly enough slideup(); is not working! ahhhhh its driving me crazy lol

Comment: I have updated the post to include all the correct code etc, could you kindly upvote, I accepted your answer.